# Some questions about the Cortex-M3 bit-banding feature

Tags: cortex-m, bit-banding

(I am new to ARM microcontrollers. Pardon me if this is a naïve question. )

ARM-M3 processor provides a unique bit-banding feature which maps a bit in the first 1M address range of SRAM and peripheral regions to a 32-bit word in another alias address ranges, respectively.

My questions are:

- Why only map the first 1M? What's so special about this first 1M range?
- The mapped 32M alias ranges are still in the SRAM/Peripheral range, so they cannot be used for other purpose, right?
- If I want to set a bit in the bit-banding region, should I write `0xFFFFFFFF`, `0x000000FF` or just `0x1` to the mapped alias word? It seems all of them can work but I am not sure which one is safe/correct.

Comment: The first 1MB, because arm chose to, you can ask them

Comment: Bit [0] of the value written to a word in the alias region determines the value written to
the targeted bit in the bit-band region. Writing a value with bit [0] set writes a 1 to the
bit-band bit, and writing a value with bit [0] cleared writes a 0 to the bit-band bit.
Bits [31:1] of the alias word have no effect on the bit-band bit. Writing 0x01 has the same
effect as writing 0xFF . Writing 0x00 has the same effect as writing 0x0E .

Comment: seems pretty clear did you read the arm docs?

Comment: I am just reading the "Designer's Guide to the Cortex-M Processor Family". I will read the specs later. Thanks for the comment.